# Cheap power tools for large number of cuts of aluminium profile lengths

Tags: tools, powertools, aluminum, metal-cutting

I need to make some 200 cuts of aluminium profiles. Examples of what I'll be cutting:

- Hollow box profile, 40mm x 40mm x 3mm:

  - 40 pieces of 400mm lengths
  - 12 pieces of 1500mm lengths
- Hollow box profile, 40mm x 40mm x 1.5mm:

  - 40 pieces of 400mm lengths
- U channel profile, 40mm x 40mm x 3mm:

  - 80 pieces of 40mm length

I need the cuts to be within a few millimetres accuracy.

How could I do this without giving myself RSI or spending a lot of money on a tool?

Thanks

Comment: Do you have a tablesaw or mitresaw or jigsaw? To me that would be best.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any circular saw will cut aluminum, copper, or any other non-ferrous metal easily with a sharp carbide-tipped blade.

Keeping the cuts straight, square, millimeter accurate and not damaging thinwall parts will require some guides. My preference would be a radial arm saw, the length is easily handled with a clamp on the fence. If you don't have one, buy or rent a cutoff saw and build a jig. Time spent building it right is repaid tenfold when you cut all those pieces.

Use a new blade - the one that made your deck 5 years ago will make a mess of the aluminum. And get some earplugs too - cutting metal tubing makes noise roughly comparable to the Space Shuttle lifting off.

Comment: Excellent - In that case, I have a mitre saw which I'd want to use. How many teeth should I be looking at for the blade? I take it it should be a CTC blade? Thanks!

Comment: I use a cheap big-box cut-off saw with carbide blade for aluminum stock up to 2X4". That thickness will start to bog down the saw If I'm not careful. Aluminum is pretty soft, but you *will* have to replace/sharpen the blade more often than you would just cutting pine and oak. If you don't, you'll start *melting* your way through the thinner pieces. That's messy and imprecise.

Comment: Don't know how much you want to invest in the project, but they make sawblades specifically for cutting non-ferrous metals. Just as an example, the Freud LU77M010. (But that's not an endorsement of that specific blade -- I haven't used it.) It has 80 teeth, a TCG tooth profile, and less hook than ordinary blades. Cut slow; wear hearing protection; throw a tarp down where the aluminum dust goes or forever hear complaints from your significant other about the sparkly driveway.

Answer (score 0):

I just cut some 1/2" 6061 aluminum using a Rockwell Versacut 3 3/8" circular saw and it worked great.  The saw came with an aluminum cutting blade which looks like a regular inexpensive steel blade. I made several strait and clean cuts thru the 1/2" aluminum without using a saw guide with no problem.  While the saw has plenty of power to cut thru the 1/2 aluminum,it has a much smaller motor and blade and less torque than a 7 1/4" circular saw so potential kickbacks should be much easier to control.  I made several long cuts and the saw never tried to bind or kickback except once when I attempted a plunge cut. The saw is very light and easy to handle and it comes with a laser guide.